# CakePHP Auth loginRedirect error/always redirect to 'users/login' whereas i put different controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication, cakephp-2.0

CakePHP Auth loginRedirect error/always redirect to 'users/login' whereas i put different controller.
I mean, when i open the forbidden page(not allowed/require login)

```
$this->Auth->allow('index', 'profile', 'view', 'register');
```

it must redirect to "players/index". I put the loginRedirect to "players",

```
'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Players', 'action' => 'index'),
```

but it doesn't work. It always redirect to "users/login" not "players/index" whereas i write "'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Players', 'action' => 'index')".

this is my code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Players', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Players', 'action' => 'index'),
        'authError'=>"Anda tidak dapat mengakses halaman.",
        'authorize'=>array('Controller')
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    return true;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'profile', 'view', 'register');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
}}
```

My table's name : players

why the result's always redirect to "users/login" not "players/" or "players/index"?
please tell me why this happens and how i can solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to lowercase controller name ? Players => players

```
'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'index'),
'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'index'),
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work when i try. Is the any way to solve this?

Comment: Ok I see now what you want, you can't define another location for error. You have to define a redirect in the else condition of your login() function in your controller.

    `public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'));
        }
    }
}`

Comment: what controller i must put this function? sorry for confusing, i have edit my question, please help me to solve this. :)

Comment: You should have a login() method in your users controller

In the else part just put the redirect :
`$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'));`

Comment: Is CakePHP only can read users controller for Auth? I would like to change users controller into players controller.

Comment: Try :
`$this->Auth->loginAction = array(‘controller’ => ‘players’, ‘action’ => ‘login’)`
and read carrefully : 
[cake_authentification](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Comment: Wow, thankyou very much! :D That's work nicely! I will read carefully from now.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with the same issue for hours. Set the login action in the `beforeFilter` of your `AppController` as following:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'yourcontollername', 'action'=>'login');
```

I followed the video [youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM), see the first reply.

Comment: Just a note to anyone trying to figure out the difference: `loginAction` controls where the application will forward the guests before they go through Auth (i.e. the page where they'll see the login form), while `loginRedirect` controls where to redirect them after they log in

Answer (score 0):

very interesting, i come across a similar problem - after login redirect to the default home page. 
I have tried all above methods, but none of them could solve the issue.

finally, i found out that login form did not build properly which action and controller were not set. therefore the html form pointed to '/', when posted. 
However, the system still managed to login to right accounts, but none of redirect function worked in this situation.

It might be something you need to look into.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the beforeFilter function in AppController.php. You must set allowances for the Auth object.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    // put in the functions that point to the views you want to be able to see 
    // without logging in. This works for all controllers so be careful for naming
    // functions the same thing. (all index pages are viewable in this example)
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'thePageIWantToSee', 'userAdd', 'landingPage');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the login() function in your Users/Players Controller. With the if cause you can redirect to an diffrent page.

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect('/account'); //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }                
            return $this->redirect( ['controller' =>'pages', 'action' => 'login-fail']);
        }
    }
```

Example used in CakePHP 3.2